# How do I extract hidden text after Table of Contents in Microsoft Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a requirement where I have to extract two lines of text just after the Table of Contents in a Word Document. The text is hidden and added just for use in VBA.

I did some research and found out that I can extract text from a word Document using the `Range` object and so I tried hardcoding it and I got the value I wanted by using

```
MsgBox ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(43).Range.Text
```

Now this code can work for a specific document but for a new document I don't know where the Table of Contents will end and the exact line number from where I have to extract.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: For non-visible storage of information in a Word document, look into using Word Custom Properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.customdocumentproperties) or Word Document Variables (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.variables). Both are more robust, secure and easier to use than storing as hidden text

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly tricky because field objects don't have a range so you have to seek the range of the Result of the field.  Once you have the result range, you can then get the paragraph range in which it sits, and then, the range of the next paragraph and then when you have that, the text of that paragraph.  Sounds complicated but in practise is quite simple when you understand how the Word object model works.

```
Sub Test()

    Debug.Print GetTextAfterToc

End Sub

Public Function GetTextAfterToc() As String

    Dim myfield As Word.Field
    
    For Each myfield In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Fields
    
        If myfield.Type = wdFieldTOC Then
        
            GetTextAfterToc = myfield.Result.Paragraphs(1).Range.Next(unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1).Text
            Exit Function
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
End Function
```

Comment: The code that is provided gives me the first line and page number of the table of Contents, i.e, the text after Table of Contents Heading. I actually need to get the text after the whole of Table of Contents, i.e, the text after ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(n).Range.Text. Sorry if the question wasn't clear.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out thanks to your code. I used `Set toc = ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1)
    afterTOCText = toc.Range.Next(unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1).Text` to get the text required.

Comment: If you could guide me on one thing, the above code just gets me one line of text, is there any I can get two lines of text at once?

Comment: Point 1.  I checked with some hidden text after a toc field before I posted and the code was working fine.  If the code doesn't work for you then there is something about your document you haven't explained.  Point 2.  My code returns the content of the first paragraph after the toc.  If you are only getting one line then it means that your two lines are in fact two paragraphs.  Thus, as you have the range of the first paragraph you need to look at the range.font.hidden property of the next paragraph and extend the range as necessary.

Comment: Point 1. I checked it a bit and the code only works if there is only once value in the Table of Contents. If there are multiple levels or values in the Table of Contents the code doesn't work since I guess its just searching for the first field and then exiting so it just selects the first value in the TOC and thus displays the second value in the TOC as the output. If somehow, it selected the last TOC value it would work. Point 2. Yes they were different paragraphs and thus not accessible at once.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question. I am posting it to help someone else with a similar question. Thanks to [u/slang4201](https://www.reddit.com/user/slang4201/) for the answer.

This will select the two lines immediately following a TOC.

```
Dim myField As Field
For Each myField In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If myField.Type = wdFieldTOC Then
        myField.Select
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Selection.MoveDown unit:=wdLine, Count:=2, Extend:=True
        MsgBox (Selection.Range)
        Exit For
    End If
Next myField
End Sub
```

However, if the lines you are looking for are hidden, they WILL NOT be selected and found unless you unhide them first.

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Font.Hidden = False
```

Hope this helps, and good luck!